# Sprite Batching: advanced technique

Tags: opengl, batch-processing, spritebatch

I'm making OpenGL2 based application, which renders over 200 sprites in each iteration. I would like to use less drawcalls, since often I render multiple sprites with same texture. Unfortunately, regular batching technique is not good for me because of Z-Sorting. Draworder of all elements is important, so I can't group them and draw by groups.

I was wondering, is there another batching technique to use in that situation. For example, I could modify shader to work with multiple textures at the same time (sounds like a bad decision though). Share your knowledge.

**UPD 09.10.13:** I also thought, that atlas textures will reduce drawcalls because of significant material number reducement.

Answer (score 1):

I found that instanced rendering could speed things up A LOT ( tracing 100000 icosahedrons at 2 FPS with normal rendering to over 60 fps with instanced rendering ). There is a good section "Instanced Rendering" in the redbook about that subject. Hope this can be applied to your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jean. It was very interesting to read this article and I found it helpful.